# Naming / Aliasing IP addresses in UFW

Tags: ufw

I've set up UFW and things are working great. I want to restrict access to 5 distinct ports for three distinct IPs.

Is there a way to either name/alias an IP, or create a group of IPs?

Right now I've setting up 15 separate rules to cover the above scenarios. It's difficult to keep track of which IP is which, not to mention the verbosity.

From my research, it seems you can set up "apps" but you're explicitly instructed *not* to specify IP in the configuration profile.